# Points nearby a line

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have a number of points in $2d$. I'm looking for a way to determinate a line, which has a maximum number of points in a given range.

There is no need that the line intercepts one of the points.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at the [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) algorithm. You can easily modify it for your needs.

RANSAC means *Random Sample Consensus* and is used for eliminating outliers. For e given 'distance' you just randomly select in your case two points (you need as many points as are needed for uniquely determine your model) and calculate the number of points that are within your distance.

This algorithm is suitable for big sets of data. As it does only take random samples, it is not guaranteed to find the optimal solution, but it usually does a pretty good job.